# Select only specific columns of CSV

Tags: r, csv

Say I have a csv with the following header (of course there is also some real content):

```
a1,a2,b1,a3,c1,b2
```

How can I select only specific columns, say columns starting with `a`?

So that I only have the following header

```
a1,a2,a3
```

Using this I can specify a range, but my desired columns are not consecutive:

```
myColumns = csv[c(1:3)]
```

Comment: For clarification, once a csv file is loaded into r (by `read.csv` or some other function), it's actually an R object (usually a data.frame). To an R user, asking to get columns from a csv would be asking them to only selectively read those columns in from the csv, so that R never even knows about the other ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
myColumns = csv[,c("a1", "a2", "a3")]
```

Gets you the just those columns. If you want to select all columns *(edit) that start* with "a":

```
csv[,grep("^a", names(myColumns))]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to read selected columns into R directly from the csv file without reading the entire file, you could try this method with `fread()`.

```
library(data.table)
fread(file, select = grep("^a", names(fread(file, nrow = 0L))))
```

This reads only the first line of the file (the header) and then uses `grep()` to determine where the values that begin with `a` are. Then we use that result in the column selection argument `select` to get the columns we want.

Let's try it out with `mtcars`, finding only the columns that begin with `d`.

```
## write mtcars to file
write.csv(mtcars, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, file = "mtcars.csv")
## now read only the columns beginning with 'd'
DT <- fread("mtcars.csv", select = grep("^d", names(fread("mtcars.csv", nrow = 0L))))
## have a look
head(DT)
#    disp drat
# 1:  160 3.90
# 2:  160 3.90
# 3:  108 3.85
# 4:  258 3.08
# 5:  360 3.15
# 6:  225 2.76
```

Comment: despite the question title, looks like the csv is already an R object

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
> a1 <- c(0, 1, 2)
> a2 <- c(3, 4, 5)
> a3 <- c(6, 7, 8)
> csv <- data.frame(a1, a2, a3)
> csv
  a1 a2 a3
1  0  3  6
2  1  4  7
3  2  5  8
> csv[,c("a1", "a3")]
  a1 a3
1  0  6
2  1  7
3  2  8
```